# Can a Health Assessment Questionnaire Score be negative?

Tags: health-informatics

I am an ESL editor and I came across a manuscript where the authors mentioned a mean Health Assessment Questionnaire score of 0.47±0.64. This seemed odd to me because the **(-) part would go into negative**. It is possible that the number of data elements is small and the author used the sample formula rather than the population formula for standard deviation.

Comment: Please link your sources.

Comment: My apologies. I cannot. It is a manuscript I am editing. Unpublished.

Answer (score 2):

It's common for people to use mean and standard deviation in situations where it doesn't make a lot of sense. Sometimes it's okay, but yes it can lead to weird behavior like you've described. You should not interpret "+/-" here to mean that the values range from 0.47-0.64 to 0.47+0.64, just that the standard deviation is 0.64. Whether it makes sense to think of a standard deviation for these data is another matter.

This doesn't have anything to do with sample vs population standard deviation. Imagine your data are six 0s and two 2s:

[0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2]

The mean is 0.5. The standard deviation is about 0.9. You could report that as 0.5 +/- 0.9 but that doesn't really describe the data very well.

Comment: Thank you very much. That really answered my question perfectly!